# ReportServer database deadlock on dbo.DataSource table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I get several deadlocks a day on the DataSource table with the stored procedures dbo.AddDataSource and dbo.GetDataSources.  They are page level locks.  Any ideas on how to alleviate the situation?

XML Deadlock Graph:

```
<deadlock>   <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process1d1df6548c8" />   </victim-list>   <process-list>
    <process id="process1d1df6548c8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:11004 " waittime="2057" ownerId="7905394629" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2019-01-03T09:58:26.103" XDES="0x1c61d053a40" lockMode="S" schedulerid="6" kpid="5472" status="suspended" spid="311" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2019-01-03T09:58:26.103" lastbatchcompleted="2019-01-03T09:58:26.103" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.103" clientapp="Report Server" hostname="FMS-SQL2016" hostpid="14792" loginname="NT SERVICE\ReportServer" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7905394629" currentdb="5" currentdbname="ReportServer" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="ReportServer.dbo.GetDataSources" line="8" stmtstart="200" stmtend="2868" sqlhandle="0x03000500394a6d31fe340400eea8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
*password-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf> Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 829246009]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1c87b3a28c8" taskpriority="0" logused="1012" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:245381 " waittime="2059" ownerId="7905394609" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-01-03T09:58:26.100" XDES="0x1cc631e4ee0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="2" kpid="12924" status="suspended" spid="316" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-01-03T09:58:26.107" lastbatchcompleted="2019-01-03T09:58:26.107" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.107" clientapp="Report Server" hostname="FMS-SQL2016" hostpid="14792" loginname="NT SERVICE\ReportServer" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7905394609" currentdb="5" currentdbname="ReportServer" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="ReportServer.dbo.AddDataSource" line="56" stmtstart="3944" stmtend="5074" sqlhandle="0x0300050000267930fc340400eea8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
*password----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf> Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 813245952]   </inputbuf>
    </process>   </process-list>   <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="11004" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="ReportServer.dbo.DataSource" id="lock1c4ef2b1700" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594043301888">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1c87b3a28c8" mode="IX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1d1df6548c8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="245381" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="ReportServer.dbo.DataSource" id="lock1c4fcf6f780" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594043301888">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1d1df6548c8" mode="S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1c87b3a28c8" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>   </resource-list> </deadlock>`
```

Comment: You need to [analyze those deadlocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/analyze-deadlocks-with-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017). Here is [one good blog](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/) on it, and here [is another](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-are-sql-server-deadlocks-and-how-to-monitor-them/)

Comment: I've analyzed it down the pages that it is locked on, I just don't understand what is causing it on the reporting server database.  The GetDataSources is what gets killed by the deadlock and it is only reading data.  Is it possible it's a scale issue we do have over 25,000 data sources?